# Simple PHP for loop error

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

Just started learning. Here's what I have:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
$num = $i * 12;

for ($i=0; $i<13; $i++) {

echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");
}

?>
```

The outcome **should** be:

```
1 times 12 = 12

2 times 12 = 24

3 times 12 = 36
```

etc...

The outcome I actually get is:

```
1 times 12 = 0

2 times 12 = 0

3 times 12 = 0
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have this declaration before **for** loop:

```
$i = 0; $num = $i * 12;
```

so always `$num` will be `0`. Just place it into **for**:

```
for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {
   $num = $i*12;
   echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");
}
```

You don't need declare **$i** variable before for loop. This variable will be overwritten. There is simple test:

```
$i = 5;
for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++);

echo $i;
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
10
```

Comment: So it is scope problem basically **?** outer `i` and `i` in for loop are different **?** is it so?

Comment: For statement declares $i variable in the start. It will overwrite previous variable $i.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i = 1; $num = 1;

for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {
 $num = $i * 12;

echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that result you should put the calculation inside the `for` loop and start `i` with 1

```
<?php 
for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {
    $num = $i * 12;
    echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<?php
$num = 12;

for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {

    echo("$i times 12 = ".$num*$i);
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for ($i=0; $i<13; $i++) {

    echo($i." times 12 = ".$i*12."<br>");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line `$num = $i * 12;` shift into loop

```
<?php 
$i = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<13; $i++) {

    $num = $i * 12;

    echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **$num** variable only ever increments on **$i** when its 0, try putting it in the for loop like this.

```
$i = 0;


for ($i=0; $i<13; $i++) {
    $num = $i * 12;
    echo($i." times 12 = ".$num."<br>");
    }
```